# Scheduled Agent memory leak

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8, scheduled-tasks

Greeting everybody, i'm having a problem of memory leak in ScheduledAgent of my WP8 app. What i'm trying to do, is update multipe tiles of the app in a loop, and it seems ok (in regard of memory usege), but for some reason memory is not released after a tile is updated.

My code looks like this (memory usage mesured by Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage):

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    try
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
         {
             // 5MB used
             foreach (int id in myIdsList)
                UpdateTile(id);
         });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            Debugger.Break();
    }

    NotifyComplete();
}
```

The update method looks like this:

```
public void UpdateTile(int id)
{
    MyClass myClassInstance = GetInstanceById(id);

    //~6MB used by now

    Canvas drawingSurface = new Canvas();

    //Add some Image objects to canvas (source to each image is a filePath 
    // contained in myClassInstance)
    //~7MB

    WriteableBitmap bigTileImage = new WriteableBitmap(691, 336);
    bigTileImage.Render(drawingSurface, null);
    bigTileImage.Invalidate();

    //~9MB

    var bigTilePath = string.Format(/*path here*/);

    using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = 
           IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (storage.FileExists(bigTilePath))
            storage.DeleteFile(bigTilePath);

        using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
            bigTilePath, FileMode.Create, storage))
        {
            bigTileImage.SaveJpeg(isoFileStream, bigTileImage.PixelWidth,
                                  bigTileImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        }
    }

    ShellTile tileToUpdate = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(
        x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("TileID="+id));
    FlipTileData flipTileData = new FlipTileData()
    {
        //Set fields
        WideBackgroundImage = 
            new Uri(("isostore:/"+bigTilePath, UriKind.Absolute),
    };

    tileToUpdate.Update(flipTileData);

    //~10MB used
    //Shouldn't memory be released by now??
    // calling GC.Collect() has no effect
}
```

So, it's a PeriodicTask, and i have memory cap of 11MB and as far as memory is not releasing after an iteration i get OutOfMemoryException.

Maybe I do not understand the basics, but i think that most of taken memory should be released after saving file to IS (or whenever GC decides to collect, but, as I said even explicitly calling `GC.Collect()` has no effect)?

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to release the memory?

Comment: Try using a memory profiler like [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) and see whether your asumption is right/wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to call GC.Collect() after the method is executed? That is, in OnInvoke, call GC.Collect() after UpdateTile(). Calling the collector at the end of the method will not have effect as you're still keeping the references to all the objects.

Comment: You never dispose `bigTileImage`.

Comment: @gjulianm, yes i tryed - no effect, meory still not releacing

Comment: @leppie bigTileImage is Writable bitmap, which is not implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable';

Comment: By the way, i made an experiment: i took all the variables satements out of the method, and put all method content inside try block. So as a result i saw, that when it comes to "finally" block **ALL** variables are **null**, but memory still not releaced...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the sole reason for your memoryleak problem but; you're creating a tile object and 1) you're not using it 2) you're not freeing it either.

> ShellTile tileToipdate = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x =>
>   x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("TileID="+id));

what does this **tileToipdate** object do? you're not using it after querying it. if it's no use, just remove it and see if it'll make any change.

if you're going to use this object, call **tileToipdate.Finalize()** method (after you're done with it), which is [mentioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) here , quoting "Allows an object to try to free resources and perform other cleanup operations before the Object is reclaimed by garbage collection. (Inherited from Object.)"

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry,i misstyped there (not in real code, just when was writing this post) "tileToipdate" is "tileToUpdate" and it's used to update the tile ( tileToUpdate.Update(flipTileData);).

Comment: well, you're still not disposing the object.

Comment: unfortunately it's not disposable, and the `.Finalize()` method is protected, so, it can't be called from my code.